# How to Load an Array from .json file into App

Tags: java, json, android-studio

My plan is do analyze an image via tensorflow and send the result to an app. Der result is written in a json file. The json file looks like that:

`{"file": "image.jpg", "objects": [{"bbox": [177, 14, 508, 773], "label": "spanishguitar", "prob": 0.7284}]`

my class in android studio is:

`

```
    private class Downloadjson extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    String name;
    String label;

  public Downloadjson(String name) {
        this.name = name;

    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String url = SERVER_ADRESS + name;
        sleep(5000);
        //animation start

        for (int i = 0; i < 600; i++) {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(getHttpRequestParams());
            HttpGet getJson = new HttpGet(url);
            try {
                HttpResponse jsonResponse = client.execute(getJson);
                if (200 == jsonResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode()) {
                    try {

                        InputStream inputStream = jsonResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                        String json = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
                        Downloadjson downloadjson = new Gson().fromJson(json, Downloadjson.class);
                        String label = downloadjson.label;


                        TextView Result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
                        Result.setText("Your instrument could be a " + downloadjson.label);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }





                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }



            //exucte
            sleep(5000);

        }
        //stop animation


        return null;
    }
```

`

When I change "label" to "file" it works and the output is "image.jpg". But i need the "label" array with the output "spanishguitar".  So, I think the problem is, that the object is not "label" but "objects" (in my json file). And label is an array? Do you know what I have to change to get the "label" ?

Comment: "load into app" how?  You have this tagged as javascript, yet none of this is javascript logic

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you just need to properly traverse the json and assign value for `label`. Please try:

```
String label = downloadjson.objects[0].label;
```

Comment: Thank you! But after change to                                                                                             `InputStream inputStream = jsonResponse.getEntity().getContent();
                            String json = IOUtils.toString(inputStream);
                            Downloadjson downloadjson = new Gson().fromJson(json, Downloadjson.class);
                            String label = downloadjson.objects[0].label;`     the error is : "array type expected found java.lang.string"